# Checking two string in python?

Tags: python

let two strings

```
s='chayote'
d='aceihkjouty'
```

the characters in string `s` is present in `d` Is there any built-in python function to accomplish this ?

**Thanks In advance**

Comment: To help people help you, it's usually a good idea to be even more specific.  By "the characters in string `s` present in `d`", do you mean you care, or don't care, about multiplicity?  For example, if `s = "aabbcc"` and `d = "abc"`, do you want True (because `a`, `b`, and `c` are in `d`), or False, because there are 2 `a` characters in `s` and only 1 in d?

Answer (score 5):

Using [sets](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> set("chayote").issubset("aceihkjouty")
True
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> set("chayote") <= set("aceihkjouty")
True
```

Comment: You beat me...this is the classical way to do it because the problem is inherently a problem of Set theory.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> s='chayote'
>>> d='aceihkjouty'
>>> all(x in d for x in s)
True
>>>
```

The code will return `True` if all characters in string `s` can be found in string `d`.

---

Also, if string `s` contains duplicate characters, it would be more efficient to make it a set using [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
>>> s='chayote'
>>> d='aceihkjouty'
>>> all(x in d for x in set(s))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for i in s:
    if i in d:
        print i
```